# Click div to uncheck to hide on results filter

Tags: jquery, forms, list, checkbox, filter

Simply we have form that have 4 checkboxs with filter results (hide values 
when checked)

check it in new fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ag263ms9/1/

if you checked Computers checkbox it will filter and hide its results 
( Result 2, Result 4) to be
-------
Result 1
Result 3 
--------
then if unchecked, it will show its results again to be 
-------

Result 1
Result 2
Result 3
Result 4


>>simply need click div #Computers to uncheck and do same uncheck effects
(hide its results)

can you help

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $(':checkbox').click(function() {
        if($(':checkbox:checked').length > 3){
            alert('you can not check more than 3 checkboxes');
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
  })



///// Filter Results
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
{
    var $lis = $('.results > li'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');

    if ($checked.length)
    {
        var selector = $checked.map(function ()
        {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');
var $results =  $lis.hide().filter(selector) ;

        if($results.length > 0) {
            $('.no-results-found').remove();
            $results.show();
        } else {
            $('.results').append('<li class="no-results-found">No results found.</li>');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $lis.show();
    }

//click to uncheck

$('#sso').on('click', function (ev) {
        $("#aa").prop("checked", false);
var $results =  $lis.show().filter(selector) ;
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="tags">
    <label><input id="ss" type="checkbox" rel="arts" /> Arts </label>
    <label><input id="aa" type="checkbox" rel="computers" /> Computers </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="health" /> Health </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" /> Video Games </label>
</div>
<p/><p/><hr/>
<div id="sso">Click to uncheck #Computers</div>
<p/><p/><hr/>


<ul class="results">
    <li class="arts computers">
        Result 1
    </li>
    <li class="video-games">
        Result 2
    </li>
    <li class="computers health video-games">
        Result 3
    </li>
    <li class="arts video-games">
        Result 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the syntax for links is `[link text](http://example.com)`

Comment: @madshogo yes, and you are not allowed to link to `jsfiddle` without providing some code as well.

Comment: don't quite get the question, Could you explain the problem better?

Comment: We edited a question,now can you help                         question in simple                                                 .1- click div > uncheck input > filter result                       OR                                                                   2- click to uncheck effects like normal uncheck

Comment: if I understand your question right, then the fiddle does what you want.